# Is getting a SSL certificate and key pair necessary for using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ssl-certificate, pgadmin

I recently installed pgadmin 4 and Posgtres Enterprise Manager after installing PostgreSQL v11. However I then encountered issues with SSL while trying to normally set up and use pgadmin and PEM.

In a previous question I posted here, a user advised that I add a SSL cerificate and key to my PostgreSQL installation as stated in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html).
Is this a necessary step do if I only plan on using these softwares for personal development? And if so, can anyone recommend reliable ways to get a SSL certificate and key pair?

Comment: Slightly offtopic: Are you sure about PostgreSQL v11? That version is EOL within a few months, why do you spend time on this? Advice: Take a recent version, like 15, or maybe even the Beta version 16. SSL is only required if you want to use SSL. I don't use it for any local database cluster on my laptop, used for local development.

Comment: The application I'm using this for doesn't support v14 or v15 yet. However, I'll try upgrading to 12 or 13 instead.

Comment: v12 is EOL next year, you keep on migrating if you use old versions. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither pgadmin nor PostgreSQL itself fundamentally require SSL, although you could configure them to require it.  I don't know what PEM does, but I would be surprised if it had an absolute requirement for SSL--maybe there own support channel would be the best place to ask.

The [docs themselves](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-CERTIFICATE-CREATION) tell you how to create certs.  It is not the last word on the subject, as it is the docs for PostgreSQL, not for OpenSSL nor for RFC 6101 itself. But it should be a good starting point.  PostgreSQL does not integrate with your system trust store (until v16, but even then not by default), so there isn't a point in getting a certificate signed by one of the browser-or-system-trusted CAs.